# Using 'confirm' with 'if'

Tags: conditionals

Let me tell you the scenario first. I asked my previous to give me some work on my weekends and my manager has told me that I can work on Saturdays from 7 am to 5 pm. Now tomorrow is Saturday and asked my employer the following sentence:

> Good morning Josie, as tomorrow is Saturday, I'm just confirming if I'm working tomorrow.

She said I am going to commence my work on the 23rd which is the next Saturday.

Comment: this is not a conditional construction. 'if' here is synonymous with 'whether'

Comment: As green_ideas says - English speakers use **if** all the time when they mean **whether**. **If** is really conditional - **I'll come if it doesn't rain**. To say **I'm confirming if I am working** means **whether I am working**. Your sentence should read: **...as tomorrow is Saturday, may I confirm whether I am working tomorrow?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @AIQ Yeah, and what does the "I asked my previous to give me some work" mean?

Comment: Probably better ask at interpersonal SE or or workplace SE. Thank you.